# What is the purpose of HttpClient.BaseAddress and why can't I change it after the first request

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

So most of us have probably read that we are supposed to reuse instances of `HttpClient` instead of using `using` and creating new ones. That means I can just create a single instance of `HttpClient` in my program and call `GetAsync` using a full uri string per request. This leads me to the `BaseAddress` property of `HttpClient`. Consider the following code:

```
HttpClient microsoftClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com/") };
HttpClient stackoverflowClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/") };

var response = microsoftClient.GetAsync("about").Result;
Console.WriteLine($"I {((response.IsSuccessStatusCode) ? "can" : "cannot")} access microsoft.com/about from the microsoft client");

response = microsoftClient.GetAsync("trademarks").Result;
Console.WriteLine($"I {((response.IsSuccessStatusCode) ? "can" : "cannot")} access microsoft.com/trademarks from the microsoft client");

response = stackoverflowClient.GetAsync("company/about").Result;
Console.WriteLine($"I {((response.IsSuccessStatusCode) ? "can" : "cannot")} access stackoverflow.com/company/about from the stackoverflow client");

response = stackoverflowClient.GetAsync("https://www.microsoft.com/about").Result;
Console.WriteLine($"I {((response.IsSuccessStatusCode) ? "can" : "cannot")} access microsoft.com/about from the stackoverflow client");

microsoftClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com");
response = microsoftClient.GetAsync("company/about").Result;
Console.WriteLine($"I {((response.IsSuccessStatusCode) ? "can" : "cannot")} access stackoverflow.com/company/about from the microsoft client, after changing the BaseAddress");
```

Up until the last block this code runs fine, even when using the client with the stackoverflow `BaseAddress` to access Microsoft. However this code throws an `InvalidOperationException` at the beginning of the last block, when reassigning the `BaseAddress`, stating

```
'This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.'
```

This leads me to the following questions:

1. What is the benefit of using `BaseAddress` at all? I could just always use the full address in my `GetAsync` call. Is it just for the convenience/performance of not having to build the the full request string? My guess was that it would only create a single `ServicePoint` internally as described in the first paragraph of [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit/) (or something similar as the post is quite old).
2. What happens internally that we can't change a property of `HttpClient`, especially `BaseAddress`, after sending the first request? This seems quite inconvenient if using this property actually yields benefits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For (1), a common use case would be a client which interacts with exactly one server. Maybe it's the back-end API that this client was built to use. The exact details will be stored in a config file that the client reads during startup.

We could litter our code with direct accesses to the config, or inject the string read from config into every place that needs to construct a full URL. Or we could just configure the `BaseAddress` of the HttpClient we're putting into our Dependency Injection container and just let the consuming locations have that object injected. That for me is a somewhat expected use case.

For (2), I don't think there's a *technical* limitation. I think this is more there to save people from themselves. Since setting a `BaseAddress` and causing an actual request to go out via e.g. `GetAsync` are separate actions, it would be unsafe for two separate pieces of code to be doing such a thing at the same time - you could easily get races. So it's easier to reason about multi-threaded programs that may be sharing a single instance of `HttpClient` if such races aren't allowed in the first place.

Comment: This is definitely a good answer and highlights aspects that I have not even thought about. I will accept this if no one can come up with a better (i.e. technical) explanation.

Comment: According to your answer, in a situation where you have many requests to few base addresses (i.e. 5), it would be advisable to have 5 `HttpClient` instances with `BaseAddress` set instead of a single one for all requests?

Comment: @JeromeReinländer - if they're all of roughly equal "weight", that's probably what I'd do. So we have a setup where we have a "Client" REST service, a "Notes" REST service and a "Colleague" REST service. Each service includes lots of rich internal links in its responses and these are all relative rather than absolute URLs. So a client consuming all of these services would be given 3 HttpClient instances configured with the base addresses for the appropriate environment/service combination and can easily interact with each service as needed.

Answer (score 5):

2 purposes:

1. Convenience. If you're calling many endpoints off a single host, and you're managing the base address and endpoint segments as separate strings (very common), it helps you avoid doing ugly string concatenation on every call.
2. Encouraging best practices. Although making calls via `GetAsync`, etc. is thread safe, `HttpClient` has several properties in addition to `BaseAddress`, such as `DefaultRequestHeaders`, that are not. Very typically, you want these to be the same for calls to the same host but not for calls to different ones. For this reason, **an `HttpClient` instance per host being called** is actually a very good practice. Unless you're calling thousands of different hosts, you don't need to worry about [the infamous socket exhaustion problem](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) here. (And even if you were using a singleton, the underlying network stack would need to open a different socket per host anyway.)

So why does specifying a full address on an `HttpClient` call even work at all? Again, convenience. The address might be coming from an external source or user input, and you wouldn't want to have to break it into pieces in order to use it. But in this case, you are on the hook for thread safety, and those non-thread-safe properties should probably just be avoided entirely.