# Changing the Base Address of a HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

When writing an application that uses HttpClient I have the same approach as [this post](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), in other words *I don't use using* and instead use a static HttpClient. I have had no problems with that when I want to communicate with only one server. (I set the Ip address as `BaseAddress` and proceed)

Now I have the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319777/what-is-the-purpose-of-httpclient-baseaddress-and-why-cant-i-change-it-after-th) regarding the fact that BaseAddress can not be changed after starting to use the HttpClient.

That question's answers respond with an explanation that it can not be done. You can not change BaseAddress.

So my question (which is *different* than the linked one so not a duplicate) is what to do if we want to change the ip adress to communicate with other server?

Should we instantiate another HttpClient? (no, we are not going to use `using`) How do we correctly proceed from here?

Comment: then do not set base address and just use the full addresses for the requests. That way the same http client can be used for all requests other wise you would need to create a new client for each base address which will also defeat the purpose of having the single client.

Comment: actually you CAN change BaseAddress. At least in my net core 3 project I do. 
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(newAddress);

Comment: The `BaseAddress` property has a setter so you CAN change it (in .NET 5) but only BEFORE you send the first request (after that you'll get an exception, see the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L76) specifically the call to `CheckDisposedOrStarted()` on line 87).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As it stands you can't change the base address.

> How do we correctly proceed from here?

Do not set the base address and just use the full addresses for the requests.

That way the same client can be used for all requests other wise you would need to create a new client for each base address which will also defeat the advantages of having the single client.

The client factory in asp.net core 2+ has since fixed the problems associated with having multiple clients.

> Disposing of the client is not mandatory, but doing so will cancel any ongoing requests and ensure the given instance of HttpClient cannot be used after Dispose is called. The factory takes care of tracking and disposing of the important resources that instances of HttpClient use, which means that HttpClient instances can be generally be treated as .NET objects that don’t require disposing.
>
> One effect of this is that some common patterns that people use today to handle HttpClient instances, such as keeping a single HttpClient instance alive for a long time, are no longer required. Documentation about what exactly the factory does and what patterns it resolves will be available, but hasn’t been completed yet.

Completed documentation [Use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: So I guess the next question would be, if somehow I want the IP address of the server taken from settings and not changed during running, what would be the best approach? (I guess reading a text file is possible but is it the best way?)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the `BaseAddress` by making a new one instance of `HttpClient`.

Let's say you have a handle holding the `HttpClient` in your class.

```
public HttpClient Client { get; set; }
```

Then in your code:

```
public void InitializeMyStuffAndFetchBaseAddress() {
  Client = new HttpClient();
  // do something with the Client, let's say we
  // wanna fetch what's the base address we should use
  string url = "https://www.myserver.com/getaccess";
  string baseAddress = await Client.GetStringAsync(url);
  ...
  Client.Dispose();
  
  Client = new HttpClient();
  Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress );
  ...
}
```

So in terms of the code using the `Client` is transparent to them even if you spawn a new instance of `HttpClient`.