# Changing a default request header for HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

A bit related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195967/changing-the-base-address-of-a-httpclient) I have the following:

```
public static HttpClient client= new HttpClient();
//Basic HTTP client setup
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(address);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("custom_header", "MyCustomHeader");
```

As you can see I set a base address (the matter of the previous question) that I can not change, and I set a custom header.

My question is can I change later in code this custom header (temporarily or permanently)?

For example I want my requests have the header "MyCustomHeader" but for some particular request, I want it to be "MyOtherHeader".

Is this possible, and if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: what have you tried so fat? ie show us your attempts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand, you want to add/remove this custom header on runtime.

You can add custom header like code below,

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("custom_header", "MyCustomHeader");
```

And, you can remove header when you want with code below

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("custom_header");
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to just *change* , should I remove and add another value?

Comment: RequestHeader is KeyValuePair and KeyValuePair Value property is read only. So you should remove and add again with another value.

Comment: This of course will affect the default header permanently, is that right? (Until changed back I mean)